# What are the names of these components in C#?

Tags: c#, components

I am looking for components marked as 1 and 2 in the diagram below. What are these called in C#?

I am pretty sure no.2 is not a `ListView`.

[image]

Comment: Top is MenuStrip and bottom is a ListView in Details mode and with Groups

Comment: You don't mean the 'right-click' menu for #2 do you? That would be a ContextMenuStrip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control #1 is a [ToolStrip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e58c44b8(v=vs.110).aspx) with its [GripStyle()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.gripstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) property set to false.  The images on it are [ToolStripButtons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) with their Image() property set to the image, and their [ImageScaling()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.ImageScaling);k(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton);k(VS.Properties);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2)&rd=true) property set to none.  The vertical line is simply a Separator.

Drop a ToolStrip on your Form and it will be fairly easy to figure out.

Control #2 is actually a [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) using [Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.groups(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The first component is ToolStrip Control
The second component is ListView Control. its similar to left portion of windows explorer.

Listview has diff. views which you can change as below

```
            ListView1.View = View.Details;
            ListView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
            ListView1.View = View.List;
            ListView1.View = View.SmallIcon;
            ListView1.View = View.Tile;
```

Also inside listview in your diagram you have a popup menu. that control is ContextMenu.

Regards